# A PowerShell script to move files to a folder based on their names?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder c:\test with files:

- Raport-en-us-Country1.xlsx
- Raport-en-us-Country2.xlsx
- Raport-en-us-Country3.xlsx

etc.

and I want to

1. create folders based on the last part of the file name
2. move files to the new folders
3. if the file already exist the old file should be overwritten

Example: `c:\test\Raport-en-us-Country1.xlsx` should go to `c:\test\Country1\Raport-en-us-Country1.xlsx`.

Can anyone help me to create a PowerShell script for this, please?

I have this code, it creates the folder/s but it doesn't move the files:

```
# 1. Get a list of files in the c:\test folder
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test;

# 2. Parse file names, create folder structure, and move files
foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    $File.Name -match '(?<folder>.*?)(?:-)(?<subfolder>\w{2})(?:-)(?<filename>.*)';
    if ($matches) {
        $Destination = 'c:\test\{0}\{1}\{2}' -f $matches.folder, $matches.subfolder, $matches.filename;
        mkdir -Path (Split-Path -Path $Destination -Parent) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $Destination -WhatIf;
    }
    $matches = $null
}
```

Comment: split the `.BaseName` on the `-`, take the last part, create a dir with that name, then move the file. that covers the concept. [*grin*] ///// since this is NOT a code writing service - it's a "help fix my code" site - you will need to show your code and what is not working OR go to a site like SuperUser to get someone to write the code for you.

Comment: Remove the `-WhatIf` switch?